# Library for device drivers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, device-driver

I made a library for mapping into a memory address any PE format file, the thing is i did it only user land, using Visual Studio 2013 with standar .lib format. Does this means that my library cant be used inside a device driver?

For example i have the following snippet:

```
    HMODULE ntdllmod = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
    if (ntdllmod)
    {
        ZwQueryInformationProcess func = (ZwQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(ntdllmod, "ZwQueryInformationProcess");
    }
```

This works well on user land, but on kernel i dont need to call GetProcAddress, i just can call ZwQueryInformationProcess directly, since its a ntoskrnl export... Cant i just do this for example?:

```
#IF USER_LAND
   HMODULE ntdllmod = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
   if (ntdllmod)
   {
       ZwQueryInformationProcess func = (ZwQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(ntdllmod, "ZwQueryInformationProcess");
   }
#elif KERNEL_MODE
   //Run my Kernel version code here.
```

If this is not possible then how i can build a device driver library in VS2013? (cant find the option) Also any guide or reference for knowing how to link drivers library would help, assuming its different than a normal library.

**EDIT: I already know about using ZwQueryInformationProcess, the question is if i can use the preprocessor directive #IF to generate a driver library or a user mode library and having both implementations in the same solution.**

Thanks.

Comment: Driver (kernel mode) API's are different from user mode API's. I haven't looked this particular function up, but there are MANY user-mode functions that are either not available, or available through a different route in driver code. This is typically because the developers of Windows felt there is no requirement to provide that functionality (in that form). It would probably help if you explained exactly why you need to load a PE in kernel mode - maybe there is another way to achieve what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks i already knew that, the question is if i can use preprocessor directive (#IF) to use kernel export functions from the WDM SDK and a the same time use win32 normal APIs. In theory compiler should create the library according the preprocessor directive and would be for kernel land or user land, but i dont know if this is possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `#if` to produce different code where necessary. You will probably have to define your own `-D` or `#define` to control whether the library is "kernel" or "user mode".

It is often best to separate out the "functions that aren't generic" into one or a few modules (and including the files, say "usermode-stuff.c" and "kernel-stuff.c", respectively as part of the project source files), where the same type of function is declared for generic use. This avoids having a huge number of `#if KERNEL_MODE` all over the code, which can get quite messy after a while.

Obviously, that in itself doesn't necessarily mean that you can do all the things you need, or that your project can be achieved - there isn't enough details in your question to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

I would explain about only ZwQueryInformationProcess function's case.
ZwQueryInformationProcess is already exported by ntoskrnl.exe , 
and then you can use it easily.

1. include header file.

ex) #include "ntddk.h"

1. or declare ZwQueryInformationProcess
   ex)

NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwQueryInformationProcess(
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle, 
    IN ULONG ProcessInformationClass, 
    OUT PVOID ProcessInformation, 
    IN ULONG ProcessInformationLength, 
    OUT PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL);

1. add ntoskrnl.lib at sources file.
2. finally, you can use it. that's it.

ex)

```
ULONG GetProcessID(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PPEB* ppPeb )
{
    NTSTATUS Status;
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION ProcInfo;

    Status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle, ProcessBasicInformation, &ProcInfo, sizeof(ProcInfo), NULL);
    if (STATUS_SUCCESS == ntStatus) {
        if (ppPeb) {
            *ppPeb = ProcInfo.PebBaseAddress;
        }
        return ProcInfo.UniqueProcessId;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this allow me to use preprocessor directive to generate a driver library and a user mode library when its required?